# Cannot read private key on X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell-4.0

Win 8.1 64-bit. .NET 4.5. Powershell 4.0. (Though I think this problem is related to .NET in general and not specific to Powershell.)

I generate a self-signed certificate like this:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName 'TheIncredibleHulk' -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My
```

Then I retrieve the cert:

```
$Cert = Get-Item Cert:\CurrentUser\My\9E5A8322B890DA1247BD98BDAB288CA9D11CF99E
```

The certificate has a private key:

```
$Cert.HasPrivateKey
True
```

Or does it?

```
$Cert.PrivateKey
(null)
```

Why is the `PrivateKey` member null? How can I retrieve the private key?

Comment: I presume this is using PSPKI (https://pspki.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: @Kev No, there are no custom modules being used.

Comment: It's necessary to grant access to the private key to the user doing the access. In certmgr.msc, right-click the certificate, do "All Tasks"->Manage Private Key and grant the access.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders, but I don't believe permissions are the issue, considering that this cert is already in my own user account's personal store and I generated the cert with the same user account by which I am accessing it.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else who happens across this, I suspect the issue is related to the storage provider used by New-SelfSignedCertificate (see http://blogs.technet.com/b/vishalagarwal/archive/2010/03/30/verifying-the-private-key-property-for-a-certificate-in-the-store.aspx, which talks about a problem with the Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider and .NET classes). There's a powershell script available on [technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Self-signed-certificate-5920a7c6) that creates self-signed certificates, and defaults to using a different storage provider.

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31979731/4143285) led me to a workaround.  The issue is caused by the default provider but in the [Win10 version New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848633(v=wps.640).aspx) you can specify the provider as shown below.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName HulkSmash -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My  -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyProtection None -Provider 'Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider'
```